# InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in (wrapper dynamic-method) object:GetField (): IL_0000: ret

Tags: c#, cil

as mentioned in the title. However, im trying to do this:

```
  delegate char[] FieldDelegate();
   
  private FieldDelegate Get_InternalBuffer(StringBuilder sb)
  {
     var sbType = sb.GetType();
     var fieldInfo = sbType.GetField("m_ChunkChars", 
        BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
     
     var dynMethod = new DynamicMethod("GetField", typeof(char[]), new Type[0], true);
     ILGenerator ig = dynMethod.GetILGenerator();
     ig.Emit(OpCodes.ldflda, fieldInfo);
     ig.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
     return dynMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(FieldDelegate)) as FieldDelegate;
  }
```

Short, i have no clue why. I have inspected the IL-code of a class containing only a "char[] buffer" to simulate what im doing here and it states actually correctly this: "IL_0006:  ret " as a single IL_instruction, so what am I doing wrong?

Any help would be awesome!

best regards

Comment: This is like you have asked a question to your self. I mean there is a definite lack of information here. The question needs more clarity

Comment: what more do you need?               EDITED the delegate to show which one i try to create , sry i didnt saw that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what it actually is that you're trying to achieve, but does it have to be dynamic / use the Emit API?

If not here's a working Reflection approach:

```
private static Func<char[]> Get_InternalBuffer_Reflection_Only(StringBuilder stringBuilder)
{
   Type sbType = stringBuilder.GetType();
   FieldInfo fieldInfo = sbType.GetField("m_ChunkChars",
   BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

   Func<char[]> func = () => (char[])fieldInfo.GetValue(stringBuilder);
   return func;
}
```

There's a lot of caveats to be aware of:

- You're capturing the `StringBuilder` inside the Delegate/Func and thus tying its lifetime to the returned Delegate/Func.
- You'll have to pay the overhead of emitting/reflection every time you want to use a new `StringBuilder`

Edit:

For performance I think you can either do this with Expression or Emit. With IL I'm not sure how you'd capture the `StringBuilder` parameter in your dynamically created method, but you can slightly alter your Delegate to get the same result.

Looking over your code again the reason why it doesn't work is because you're calling `Ldfld` without there actually being anything on the stack inside your method. The `FieldInfo` alone simply describes how to get to the value, you still need a reference to the object to retrieve the value from.

Changing your Delegate you can do this:

```
delegate char[] FieldDelegate(StringBuilder sb);

private static FieldDelegate Get_InternalBuffer()
{
    Type sbType = typeof(StringBuilder);
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = sbType.GetField("m_ChunkChars",
        BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var dynMethod = new DynamicMethod("DynamicGetChunkChars", 
        typeof(char[]), new Type[] { sbType }, true);
    ILGenerator ig = dynMethod.GetILGenerator();
    ig.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ig.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldInfo);
    ig.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return dynMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(FieldDelegate)) as FieldDelegate;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder("test123");
    FieldDelegate getBuffer = Get_InternalBuffer();

    char[] ret = getBuffer(sb);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You will have to invoke the returned method with the `StringBuilder`.
This also means you can now cache the returned method and reuse it.

Comment: Yes I want the EmitApi for performance to avoid reflection code, since i will have to use this kind of method in a loop!

Comment: A pure reflection code here would rape the performance 4ever.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks alot! i justt couldnt understand quiet properly why you need to pass this Stringbuilder instance to the dynamic method and why my approach doesnt work since im also saying. "sbBuffer.GetType()" this should actually in my head atleast work as your solution? apparently not :D thx alot tho!